# FB Messenger can't receive messages

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, flask, python-requests

I am trying to setup a messenger chatbot using the newly released messenger platform api. I setup a Python Flask server hosted on Heroku and have been adapting these instruction to try to get my page receiving the messages my server sends it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/quickstart

Thus far I have validated a callback url and have been able to receive messages when I post to my page on FB (i.e. when I message my page which is linked to my app on FB, my heroku logs show that the POST request is being received). However, when I try to send messages from my server to my app, I get the following JSON error response:

```
400: {"error":{"message":"(#100) param recipient must be non-empty.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"B3cni+LAmYU"}}
```

I am using the requests library to send requests to the page. Below is the code I am using to service POST requests:

```
import json
import os
import requests

from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

FB_MESSAGES_ENDPOINT = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages"
FB_TOKEN = "EAADKWAcVj...AZDZD"

@app.route('/', methods=["POST"])
def chatbot_response():
    req_data = request.data

    data = json.loads(req_data)
    print "Data: ", data
    sender_id = data["entry"][0]["messaging"][0]["sender"]["id"]
    print "Sender id: ", sender_id
    send_back_to_fb = {
    "entry": [{"messaging": [{"recipient": {"id": str(sender_id)}}]}],
        "recipient": {
             "id": str(sender_id)},
        "message": "this is a test response message",
        "recipient": str(sender_id), "access_token": FB_TOKEN
    }

    params_input = {"access_token": FB_TOKEN, "recipient": sender_id}
    fb_response = requests.post(FB_MESSAGES_ENDPOINT,
                                params={"access_token": FB_TOKEN, "recipient":  {"id": str(sender_id)}, "json": "recipient": {"id": str(sender_id)}},
                                data=json.dumps(send_back_to_fb)) 



    print "Json of response: ", fb_response.json()

    # handle the response to the subrequest you made
    if not fb_response.ok:
        # log some useful info for yourself, for debugging
        print 'jeepers. %s: %s' % (fb_response.status_code, fb_response.text)


    return "OK", 200


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

I've tried countless different types of key/value encodings of the 'recipients' element into json but none of them seem to be understood by the FB graph service. How can I encode my request so that FB knows what the 'recipient' param is?

Thanks!

---

Edit:

It turns out I had to manually set the encoding type in the header of the POST request. Adding the following line made it so I could send interpretable text responses to FB:

```
headers = {'content-type':  'application/json'}
```

Comment: The `data` argument should be a dictionary. Did you try `data=send_back_to_fb`?

Comment: Yup I did try that! It didn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: Did you get it to work? I'm stuck with the same issue now!

Answer (score 3):

You can try these, both should work

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(send_back_to_fb), headers=headers)
```

OR

```
response = requests.post(url, json=send_back_to_fb)
```

Answer (score 0):

how about python library for using facebook messenger platform?

https://github.com/conbus/fbmq

```
from flask import Flask, request
from fbmq import Page

page = fbmq.Page(PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
  page.handle_webhook(request.get_data(as_text=True))
  return "ok"

@page.handle_message
def message_handler(event):
  page.send(event.sender_id, "HI!!!")
```